# Strange behavior of non-editable elements inside of contenteditable container in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I have the markup with non-editbale spans with user-select: none inside contenteditable div. Simplified version of it looks like this:

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  some random text
  <span contenteditable="false" style="user-select: none">1</span><span contenteditable="false"         style="user-select: none">2</span>
</div>
```

The key point here is that both spans are on one line. When I put a cursor at the end of line and press Backspace all content is deleted. When putting spans on different lines the code works as expected - `Backspace` deletes only one last non-editable elements.
Problem occurs in Chrome. FF behaves strange as well, but in another way. I only need to make it work in Chrome for now.

Physically putting spans on different lines in markup solves the problem, but it's no use, because in my case I add non-editable elements to contenteditable dynamically.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("snafu");
const button = document.getElementById("button");

const onClick = () => {
  const tag = document.createElement("span");
  tag.setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
  tag.classList.add("xml-tag");
  tag.innerHTML = "t";
  input.append(tag);
};

button.addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.input {
  color: green;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px mediumaquamarine;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.xml-tag {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-inline: 2px;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: lime;
  font-size: 10px;
  white-space: pre;
}

.button {
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px limegreen;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true" class="input" id="snafu">
      <span>Add at least 2 non-editable tags by clicking the button below. Then
          put the cursor at the end of line and press 'Backspace'</span
        >
      </div>

      <button id="button" class="button">Add me a tag, daddy!</button>
    </div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

UPD: When I tried to edit the post code snippet button appeared and I was able to add a snippet eventually.

Comment: Hi! Your off-site link has rather more code than is in the question. The way SO works, your whole question has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Doing a [mre] is great! But please put it **in** the question, [using Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: I honestly tried to add a stack snippet as it described in link you attached, but didn't succeed. The only thing that happens when I press `Cmd + M`, `Ctrl + M`  or corresponding icon is my text being formatted as a code block, Code snipped pop up doesn't appear.

Comment: Did you try clicking. the icon <> That should get you into the snippet editor. Are you saying it doesn’t?

Comment: @AHaworth, yes, I tried Chrome and FF, but it doesn't work for me for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen to keydown events of your textarea. If backspace (or delete) was pressed, get all tags and temporarily remove *user-select: none*. Then add a setTimeout(func, 0) to restore *user-select: none* after the last tag was deleted.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("snafu");
const button = document.getElementById("button");

const onClick = () => {
  const tag = document.createElement("span");
  tag.setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
  tag.classList.add("xml-tag");
  tag.innerHTML = "t";
  input.append(tag);
};

button.addEventListener("click", onClick);

// +++++ ADD THIS +++++
input.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  // if backspace or delete pressed
  if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {

    // make tags selectable, so they can be removed
    const tags = input.querySelectorAll(".xml-tag");
    tags.forEach(tag => tag.style["user-select"] = "auto");

    // make tags not selectable after deletion
    setTimeout(function() {
      tags.forEach(tag => tag.style["user-select"] = "none");
    }, 0);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.input {
  color: green;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px mediumaquamarine;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.xml-tag {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-inline: 2px;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: lime;
  font-size: 10px;
  white-space: pre;
}

.button {
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px limegreen;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true" class="input" id="snafu">
        <span
          >Add at least 2 non-editable tags by clicking the button below. Then
          put the cursor at the end of line and press 'Backspace'</span
        >
      </div>

      <button id="button" class="button">Add me a tag, daddy!</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```